# GET from terminal works but httr::GET does not

Tags: r, httr

I'm trying to download rasters from a server with `httr::GET`. We used to have this working but some changes have been made to the server and now it does not work.

Using the URL either through the browser or through GET in the terminal (ubuntu 16.04) works fine and returns a working tif raster. But using the same url from `httr::GET` does not work and gives `Status: 400`.

My only guesses are it's something to do with the encoding of the data. But I'm really not sure.

```
file <- paste0(tempdir(), '/file.tif')
r <- 
  httr::GET('https://map.ox.ac.uk/geoserver/Explorer/ows?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetCoverage&format=image/geotiff&coverageid=2015_Nature_Africa_PR&SUBSET=Long(-3,50.483779907)&SUBSET=Lat(-25.6089496609999,-11.9454326629999)&SUBSET=time(\"2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z\")',
           httr::write_disk(file, overwrite = TRUE))

ras <- raster::raster(file)

# I'm now totally confused about when and where quotes are escaped, so just to make sure...
r <- 
  httr::GET('https://map.ox.ac.uk/geoserver/Explorer/ows?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetCoverage&format=image/geotiff&coverageid=2015_Nature_Africa_PR&SUBSET=Long(-3,50.483779907)&SUBSET=Lat(-25.6089496609999,-11.9454326629999)&SUBSET=time("2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")',
            httr::write_disk(file, overwrite = TRUE))

ras <- raster::raster(file)

# But just putting the url in the browser works fine.
# https://map.ox.ac.uk/geoserver/Explorer/ows?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetCoverage&format=image/geotiff&coverageid=2015_Nature_Africa_PR&SUBSET=Long(-3,50.483779907)&SUBSET=Lat(-25.6089496609999,-11.9454326629999)&SUBSET=time("2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")

# eg 
# rr <- raster::raster('~/Desktop/2015_Nature_Africa_PR3.tif')


# And using the URL with GET in the terminal works
# GET "https://map.ox.ac.uk/geoserver/Explorer/ows?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetCoverage&format=image/geotiff&coverageid=2015_Nature_Africa_PR&SUBSET=Long(-3,50.483779907)&SUBSET=Lat(-25.6089496609999,-11.9454326629999)&SUBSET=time(\"2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z\")" > ~/Desktop/2015_Nature_Africa_PR4.tif
# eg
# rr <- raster::raster('~/Desktop/2015_Nature_Africa_PR4.tif')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrapping in `URLEncode` worked for me:

```
library(httr)
library(raster)

file <- paste0(tempdir(), '/file.tif')
url1 <- 'https://map.ox.ac.uk/geoserver/Explorer/ows?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetCoverage&format=image/geotiff&coverageid=2015_Nature_Africa_PR&SUBSET=Long(-3,50.483779907)&SUBSET=Lat(-25.6089496609999,-11.9454326629999)&SUBSET=time("2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")'

r   <- GET(URLencode(url1), write_disk(file, overwrite = TRUE))
ras <- raster(file)
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. Not sure what changed to make this be necessary but I don't care. It works.

Comment: I'll award you the bounty. I'm currently getting "you can award the bounty in 5 hours". Which I don't quite understand.